# When does the sequence $u_{n+1}=f(u_n)$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems

I have two questions:

**1)** Is there an example of  a continuous function $f$ with $f[0,1]\subset [0,1]$ such that the recursive sequence $u_{n+1}=f(u_n)$  with $u_0\in [0,1]$ does not converge?

**2)** Is there a characterization of continuous functions $f$ with $f[0,1]\subset [0,1]$ such that every recursive sequence $u_{n+1}=f(u_n)$  with $u_0\in [0,1]$ is convergent?

Comment: The [Banach fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) is a partial answer to (2) in which all the limits are the same. But there are other functions, not contraction mappings, that also meet your condition, such as $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: When is this due?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As regards the first question if $f(x)=1-x$ then the recursive sequence does not converge for any $u_0\in [0,1]\setminus\{1/2\}$.

Any continuous function $f$ such that $f[0,1]\subset [0,1]$ has a fixed point. So there is at least one point $u_0$ such that the recursive sequence does  converge.

For the second question, any [contraction mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping) has the required property but I don't know the characterization that you are asking for.